# How do I migrate part of a git repo into another repo?

Tags: git

I have two Git repos, A and B. Repo B is being retired. Some, but not all, of its files need to be merged into a branch of A, including their commit history, probably one folder at a time. That branch will eventually be used for a github PR against the master branch of A, if that's relevant.

1. How do I accomplish this?
2. If changes are made to B after the merge but before B's retirement, how do I update A with those changes?

Comment: Why do you need the history of a part of a repository? It's not better to simply copy all needed files only?

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases, I know your case is the second one but I'll leave both here so it can maybe be useful for someone else.

**Case 1**

Case 1 is when *A* and *B* share the same origin (history), therefore one can pull from the other and vice versa.

*For question 1:*

First pull repo *B* into *A*.

Then, merge *B* into *A*'s branch without committing:

```
git checkout A_branch
git merge B_branch --no-commit --no-ff
```

The files you don't want from *B* will appear as new or as new changes to *A*'s branch. Delete/discard them.

Then just commit. This way you end up just with the stuff you want from *B*.

*For question 2:*

Do the same thing again.

**Case 2**

Case 2 is when *A* and *B* are completely different, they also differ in the folder structure, that is, there's no way files would collide if you were simply copying one repo folder to another's (albeit this is not what we are going to do).

If this is the case, you can use `git subtree`. [This blog post](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/) can give more details, but basically what you want to do is, on repo *A*:

`git subtree add --prefix ./destination_folder https://your_repo.com/B.git master`

So `prefix` specifies the destination folder for repo *B*, followed by *B*'s address followed by its branch.

Refer to that blog post if you need to install `git subtree`.

Another solution to this problem is to use `git-stitch-repo`, which combines two repos creating a third one, but I think your case fits better with `git subtree`, so I'll just leave the `git-stitch-repo` URL [here](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Git-FastExport/script/git-stitch-repo).

Comment: They don't share the same history, sorry. They're entirely separate repos that serve overlapping purposes; the point of this is to get rid of one and move the bits that aren't duplicated work into the other.

Comment: Right! Do they share common files or do they have completely different folder structures?

Comment: Completely different. The components I'm migrating don't exist in the target repo (which is why they are the parts being migrated).

Comment: Another project pushed my stack, so I haven't gotten back to this yet. I haven't forgotten, though. Your solution is a start, but it looks like it will import the *entire* repository B rather than the pieces of it I need. I think I might be able to do what I want with a combination of subtree and filter-branch, though.